# What's up R 2.15 and proto?

Tags: r

I upgraded to 2.15 (I have 2.14.x and 2.13.x in my local directory).  Then, I got error messages that `proto` had no `Namespace`, re-install. That simply won't work. I `remove.packages("proto")` for all local and main libraries.  I've even tried running as root (I know), and I still get this when I attempt to install.

```
Selection: 50 trying URL
'http://cran.stat.auckland.ac.nz/src/contrib/proto_0.3-9.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 536813 bytes (524 Kb) opened
URL
================================================== downloaded 524 Kb

Loading required package: plyr

Attaching package: ‘reshape’

The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:plyr’:

    rename, round_any

Loading required package: proto Error: package ‘proto’ could not be
loaded In addition: Warning message: In library(pkg, character.only =
TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc) :   there is no
package called ‘proto’ Execution halted

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpaUy8i4/downloaded_packages’ Updating HTML index of packages
in '.Library' Making packages.html  ... done Warning message: In
install.packages("proto") :   installation of package ‘proto’ had
non-zero exit status
```

Well, yeah, `proto` doesn't yet exist, I'm trying to install it.

---

ubuntu 10.04.  2.13.x and 2.14.x installed, with ggplot2, without incident.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  grid      methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reshape_0.8.4 plyr_1.6     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.0
```

I'm going back to 2.14.2 and see if things

There appears to be a conflict with .Rprofile, in that I was able to uninstall/install 2.15 without incident after I moved it.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Maybe you should include more information about your system and the output of sessionInfo()

Comment: Works for me. `R.version.string` on my system is: `R version 2.15.0 Patched (2012-03-30 r58875)` and `win.version()` is: `Windows Vista (build 6002) Service Pack 2`.  Also `packageVersion("proto")` is: `0.3.9.2`.

Comment: ubuntu 10.04.  2.13.x and 2.14.x installed, with ggplot2, without incident.

Comment: Possibly related to http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.devel/30676 ?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to run:

```
update.packages("proto", checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

Comment: ubuntu 10.04.  2.13.x and 2.14.x installed ggplot2 without incident.